# How to sort fractions (small numbers)

Tags: algorithms, sorting

We have 100 000 fractions:
Let's consider following fractions. 
p/(2^q) such that 0 <= p,q <= 10

As you can see there are <= 10 * 10 different fractions, but we have 100 000 that we have to sort them  (so there are little unique elements).

Task is about thinking fast algorithm to sort fractions.

I ask you for looking at my proposition and show me your ideas.
(I assume that fractions are given by pair, for instance:
p/q <----> (p, q)
)
on input we have array **a**

**My idea:**

```
for i = 1 to n do t[i] = a[i].first * 2^(10)
countsort (t)
bring results from t to a (remember about / 2^10)
```

Comment: You forgot to subtract the q from the exponent.

Comment: Ok, you are right. But what about correctness and what about your ideas ?

Comment: You don't need to bring results from t to a if you make t have two fields where the second field is the subscript of the corresponding a.

Comment: What is your data type (or can that be defined)? Language restrictions? Can you use a built in sort? Why doesn't just defining the type and comparable and then tossing that into sort work?

Answer (score 3):

First, your definition of your numbers can lead to non-fractions (e.g., p=2, q=0).

Second, to summarize your idea:

1. Store all your fractions as integers
2. Perform an integer sort
3. Convert all your integers back to fractions

Seems like a lot of unnecessary memory and time when a lot of sorting algorithms can be done using a simple [comparison sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort) and you can leave your data in its original form.

With a comparison sort, you only have to implement a custom comparison operator that exploits knowledge of your specialized fractions. For example in C++, you could use the built-in [sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) function and just implement your own comparator.

The comparator function `compare(a,b)` just needs to return true if fraction `a` is less then fraction `b` otherwise return false. For example, this function can exploit the fact that multiplying by 2 can be done as a bit shift. So your comparison could look something like

```
a.first * (1 << b.second) < b.first * (1 << a.second)
```

Comment: Ok, I understand your point of view, but it is difficult to believe that we can't solve it faster (without comparison sort).

Comment: How much faster do you want to solve it? What are your requirements?

Comment: Your solution is too trivial for this problem. This task come from book, so is too simple what you proposed.

Comment: One day you may come to appreciate trivial solutions.

Comment: Ok, but it is too trivial